# Generate stream delayed from list

Tags: java

As indicated in the title, I want to generate stream from list, but the list need a large performance cost, and the stream may not be really used.

Something I need is like this:

```
Stream<T> stream = Stream.fromList(() -> calculateList(...))
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    // TODO
    ;

//#region some case why I want delayed stream instead of other way.

if (condition$1) {
    // that is why I don't want to re-order those code.
    stream.forEach(...);
    return;
}

var something$1 = ...; // that should only execute after the condition$1 not passed.

if (condition$2) {
    // that is why I don't want to use `Supplier<Stream<T>>`.
    stream = stream.concat(Stream.fromList(() -> calculateOthList(...)));
}

var something$2 = ...;

if (condition$3) {
    // that is why I dont want to use `Stream<Supplier<Stream<T>>>` (and what's more, it not easy to read).
    stream = stream.filter(...).peek(...);
}

... // as you see, the most important thing of those code is to deal the stream, it's data-driven.
//#endregion

// TODO may be return if some condition not passed.
// TODO and even worse, some exception may be throw.

stream.forEach(...); // TODO really use the stream.
```

Is there any built-in methods to do that? or maybe any way to implement elegantly?

Comment: Re-order your code so that it doesn't have a big gap between when the stream is created and when it is used.

Comment: What does `calculateList()` do?

Comment: @Michael thanks, in most time I'll re-order them, but it is not always a nice idea.
For example, may be I'll use the stream in different way by different condition, I'll edit the question and append some case, please wait me for a moment,

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Spiliterator` from a `Supplier` and get a Stream back which makes your Stream creation lazy. For example:

```
 Supplier<Spliterator<Integer>> supplier = () -> calculateList(...).spliterator();
 Stream<Integer> stream = StreamSupport.stream(supplier, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.SUBSIZED, false);
```

Comment: @zhengxiaoyao0716 can you accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing is to replace your `Stream` with a `Supplier<Stream>` e.g.

```
Supplier<Stream<T>> stream = () -> Stream.fromList(() -> calculateList(...));
```

but if you can't do that, you can implement a lazy Stream like this:

```
Stream<T> lazyStream = Stream.<Supplier<List<T>>>of(() -> calculateList())
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .flatMap(List::stream);
```

Comment: More or less, but there is no such thing as `Stream.fromList`. He made it up. It should be `() -> calculateList(...).stream()`

Comment: Thank you, in the case I actually dealing with right now, that is the best way. But maybe the delayed-stream is sitll usefully, I edit my question and append some case for it.

Comment: Well, I looked at it over again and found the the second way can also resolve my question too, I mistaked it export a stream typed `Stream.<Supplier<List<T>>>`, but in fact it just a intermediate variable, and the final export is `Stream<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you really need to provide a `Supplier`. The `Supplier` will evaluate your list populating method when you want it. There are two ways to achieve this:

```java
   Supplier<T> streamSupplier = () -> calculateList(...).stream();
   // other code
   // then use it
   streamSupplier.get().forEach(...);
```

Or maybe you really want a stream, so might do something like this:

```java
   Stream<Supplier<Stream<T>> streamOfStreamSuppliers = Stream.of(() -> calculateList().stream());
   // other code
   // then use it by unpacking the supplied stream
   // and then flatmapping that
   streamOfStreamSuppliers.map(Supplier::get)
       .flatMap(Function.identity())
       .forEach(...);
```

This has the side effect of allowing you to put multiple streams into the mix.

The bigger question, though, is why you don't reorganise your code so that your stream is created when it's first needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        Function<List<Integer>,Stream<Integer>> fnc = a->a.stream().filter(b->b%2 == 0).map(b->b*20);


        fnc.apply(list).forEach(System.out::println);
```

In your case it could be

```
       fnc.apply(calculateList(...)).forEach(....);
```